# Realloc throws stack overflow sporadically in program that calculates large integers

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, realloc

```
void inf_int::Sub(const char num, const unsigned int index)
{

    if (this->length < index) {
        char* tmp = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            cout << "Memory reallocation failed, the program will terminate." << endl;
            free(this->digits);// provided that the destructor does not call free itself
            exit(0);
        }

        this->digits = tmp;
        
        this->length = index;                   
        this->digits[this->length] = '\0';  
    }


    if (this->digits[index - 1] < '0') {    
        this->digits[index - 1] = '0';
    }

    this->digits[index - 1] -= num + '0';   


    if (this->digits[index - 1] < '0') {    
        this->digits[index - 1] += 10;  
        Sub('1', index + 1);            
    }

}
```

I am trying to make a program that calculates really large integers, using character arrays to store each digit. The compiler keeps throwing overflow error in `char* tmp = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1);` after 2 or so debugs, then after throwing errors for a few times, works again for another two tries, then repeats. Can anybody point out where I am doing wrong? Thank you.

digits is char* digits;

```
inf_int::inf_int()
{

    this->digits = new char[2]; 
    this->digits[0] = '0';      
    this->digits[1] = '\0';
    this->length = 1;
    this->thesign = true;
}

inf_int::inf_int(int n) {
    char buf[100];

    if (n < 0) {        
        this->thesign = false;
        n = -n;
    }
    else {
        this->thesign = true;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {         
        buf[i] = n % 10 + '0';

        n /= 10;
        i++;
    }

    if (i == 0) {   
        new (this) inf_int();   
    }
    else {
        buf[i] = '\0';
        this->digits = new char[i + 1];
        this->length = i;
        strcpy(this->digits, buf);
    }
}
inf_int::inf_int(const char* str)
{
    char* answer = new char[strlen(str)];
    
    if (str == NULL) {
        new (this) inf_int();
    }
    else {
        strcpy(answer, str);
        
        
        if (answer[0] == '-') {
            char* solution = new char[strlen(str)];
            this->thesign = false;
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++) {
                solution[strlen(str) -1-i] = answer[i];
            }
            solution[strlen(str)] = '\0';
            this->digits = new char[strlen(str)+1 ];
            this->length = strlen(str);
            strcpy(this->digits, solution);
        }

        else {
            char* solution = new char[strlen(str)+1];;
            this->thesign = true;//123 3

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
           
                solution[strlen(str)  - i-1] = answer[i];
            }
            solution[strlen(str)] = '\0';
            this->digits = new char[strlen(str)+1 ];
            this->length = strlen(str);
            strcpy(this->digits, solution);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: what is this  `new (this) inf_int();`  supposed to be doing?

Comment: dont use raw new, use vector, string and unique_ptr

Comment: you seem to be mixing new with realloc - no can  do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this->digits = new char[2];
```

This class member is initially allocated using `new`.

```
char* tmp = (char*)realloc(this->digits, index + 1);
```

This is undefined behavior. `realloc` is for C code that used `malloc` to allocate memory. A `realloc` of something that was originally `new`ed always ends in tears. Everything that follows from this point on is undefined behavior.

```
new (this) inf_int();
```

including this, which does not accomplish anything useful, except more undefined behavior (for completely different reasons).

It seems that, based on the entirety of the shown code, it was likely stitched together from the results of multiple keyword searches, from some search engine, instead of applying knowledge that was acquired from studying with a C++ textbook. This approach to writing C++ code rarely produces working results; additionally modern C++ rarely needs to use `new` for basic logic of the kind shown here, instead C++'s containers handle all the memory allocation for you, and correctly. For example, `std::vector` does pretty much what a good portion of this code is trying to accomplish -- allocating an initial buffer and resizing it, when needed. This is exactly what `std::vector` is for, and more information on how to use it will be found in your favorite C++ textbook.